# Generate uuid for input id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to generate random IDs for my input fields inside a v-for loop:

```
<div v-for="(data) in form" :key="data.attribute">
  <input type="date" :min="today" :id="_ + uuid()" :name="data.attribute" :placeholder="data.default_value" :readonly="data.render_type == 'readonly'" v-model="data.value" @input.prevent="updateOuter($event, data.refresh, 'due_date')"...
```

using uuid:

```
const uuid = () => {
    return v4();
};
```

When now changing the input value the ID is getting changed every time cause `uuid()` is called.
How would I generate fixed IDs for the input field using uuid?
The form data object doesn't provide unique properties I could use cause elements could appear multiple times on the page.

Comment: Using UUID in a bad method because it will change on its every render and due to this change it will affect the performance of both DOM and virtual DOM, you can use the index of loop  `v-for="(data, index) in form `  or  `data.attribute` which is used as a key in the div

Comment: @sojin I can't simply use the index cause this ID ain't unique on the page cause other components displayed there use v-for with inputs too.

Comment: Actually why should you need to add the id in vue js? you can read the input value without id right ?

Comment: @sojin I can - but I need the ID to store invalid elements after validation in Vuex.

Comment: ok use some hardcoded value + index. example `id="'SCREEN_10' + index"`. for the next screen use `"'SCREEN_11' + index"`

Comment: you can create a variable that stores the generated uuids, and next time it's called if it exist use that. data.attribute can be the key `var uuids = {}; function genUUID(name) {if(!uuids.name) uuids.name = uuid(); return uuids.name;}` and in your for `:id="_ + genUUID(data.attribute)" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should create additional object like `ids` in data and generate uuid there like below;

```
<div v-for="(data) in form" :key="data.attribute">
  <input type="date" :min="today" :id="ids[data.attribute]" :name="data.attribute" />
</div>


{
  data(){
   const ids = form.reduce((res, item) => {
     res[item.attribute]= v4();
     return res;
   }, {});

   return {
     ids,

   }
  }
}
```

Comment: That solves the problem. But I must admit, I didn't think about re-rendering when reloading the page. Then my vuex store validation wouldn't work anymore. But Thanks!